# Compass sass/scss each output value, value instead of key, value

Tags: sass, npm, compass-sass, compass

I have the following code in my scss:

http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/cebab33bec3fbe38ddc4

On my local windows machine the $color and $name is both times #000 instead of $name is `black`. (so instead of key, value its value, value whats wrong with my installation. need to get the @each work correctly with key, value)

compass --version: 1.0.3 (Polaris)
sass --version: 3.4.14

compiling with `compass compile`

Comment: The warning seems pretty self explanatory to me.  It's warning you not to use variables of type Color in your selector.

Comment: the warning has nothing todo with the code. did you have a look at the code. online in sassmeister it works but on my local machine `$color` and `$name` are the same value. and i dont no why.

Comment: First off, code that reproduces the problem **needs to be in the question**.  Second, make sure you've actually read the accepted answer in the question I marked this a duplicate of.

Comment: thx but my question is about the array map and each function which is not working as online on sass meister its not @each $key, $value in $array my local outputs $each $value, $value in $array. will delete the error message from the question because it have nothing todo with the real error.

Comment: Sass is not doing what you've described at all.  You simply don't understand the difference between String and Color.  The keys of your mapping are not Strings.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand why the code on sassmeister then works and why it dont work on my local machine?

Comment: so with the quotation it works thx. sorry was focused that the each is false or i need to install another version of sass. would better that it directly error in the error instead of change white/black to hexcode when the array is used. thank you very much.